# ESB cluster with WSO2 ELB ESB Server Errors

Tags: wso2, esb

INFO - WkaBasedMembershipScheme No responses received from WKA members
[2014-03-10 17:27:56,990]  INFO - WkaBasedMembershipScheme Sending JOIN message to WKA members...
[2014-03-10 17:27:56,996] ERROR - Axis2GroupChannel Unable to deserialize message:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{192, 168, 7, 121}:4000,{192, 168, 7, 121},4000, alive=1394443159382, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 }, payload={35 10 35 77 111 110 32 77 97 ...(61)}, command={}, domain={119 115 111 50 46 99 97 114 98 ...(21)}, ]; id={35 -20 -126 -65 124 -7 72 -95 -82 44 94 -16 -47 -25 -12 58 }; sent=2014-03-10 17:27:56.994]
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3747696661765742913, local class serialVersionUID = 9101965184867046152
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.RpcMessage.readExternal(RpcMessage.java:64)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.io.XByteBuffer.deserialize(XByteBuffer.java:568)
    at org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.Axis2GroupChannel.messageReceived(Axis2GroupChannel.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.NonBlockingCoordinator.messageReceived(NonBlockingCoordinator.java:512)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpPingInterceptor.messageReceived(TcpPingInterceptor.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector.messageReceived(TcpFailureDetector.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.DomainFilterInterceptor.messageReceived(DomainFilterInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.OrderInterceptor.messageReceived(OrderInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelCoordinator.messageReceived(ChannelCoordinator.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReceiverBase.messageDataReceived(ReceiverBase.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask.drainChannel(NioReplicationTask.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask.run(NioReplicationTask.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: What are the versions of ELB and ESB?  
Looks like the versions are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error "org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl"  class cannot be serialized, meaning you may have different version of this class in other ESB nodes.

Please check do you have any differences on jars you are using between each ESB instances (for example tribes_7.0.28.wso2v1.jar is the contains this class in ESB4.7 , so cross check similar way based on your ESB)

Answer (score 0):

tribes is out of date. Why not use hazacast instead? in ESB 4.8, clustering agent is changed.